# How could I store a Integer and a String into two-dimensional?

Tags: c

**hello**

I have a two-dimensional array of the string type, but I need to store a number and a string, how could I do this in c language?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define A 10
#define B 10

string sales[A][B];

int main(void)
{
    string product = "A";
    int age = 20;

    sales[0][1] = {'product', age};

    printf("Sales: %s\n", sales[0][1]);
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Instead of a two-dimensional array of string, make it a one-dimensional array of a { string, int } structure.

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around `product` to use it as a variable.

Comment: ok, but I need a two-dimensional. How could I store it ?

Comment: Then you can have a 2-dimensional array of structs.

Comment: `struct {string product, int age} sales[A][B];`

Comment: Good Idea. Thank You

Comment: "store a number" --> is the number an integer?  min value? max value?

Answer (score 1):

Use a struct to store a number and a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define A 10
#define B 10

typedef char *string;

struct {
    string product;
    int age
} sales[A][B]; 

int main(void)
{
    string product = "A";
    int age = 20;

    sales[0][1].product = product;
    sales[0][1].age = age;

    printf("Sales: %s\n", sales[0][1].product);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`string` is not a type in C, maybe you are refering to CS50, and in that case it's just a typedef of `char*`.

In C you can't have an array of different types, the next best thing I can think of is for you to use a structure where you can store both values associated with each other:

```
typedef struct { // structure to hold data
    char product[128]; // char array instead of pointer
    int age;
}Sales;


Sales sales[A][B]; // structure array declaration

int main(void)
{
    char product[] = "A";
    int age = 20;

    sales[0][1].age =  age;
    strcpy(sales[0][1].product, product); // here copying the data instead of pointer
                                                                                  
    printf("Sales: %s - %d\n", sales[0][1].product, sales[0][1].age);
}
```

You could use pointers instead of char arrays like Barmar did, and that's a good solution for this particular example, but be aware that pointers can become dangling if the lifetime of the data they point to expires.